# Is IE the best browser to test RESTful WebServices?

Tags: ajax, web-services, rest, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm playing with RESTful WebServices, ajax, and json.. Well.. Apparently, Chrome has some security rules that doesnt allow to test restful webservices at localhost. Curiously, using Internet Explorer all my code runs smoothly, including AJAX requests to local webservices.

Is IE the best browser to develop (testing) this kind of project ?

There's another better way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apps like Postman or Advanced REST client to test REST based webservices, Chrome is the best followed by Firefox(firebug app) and then IE.

Comment: Yes, i heard about theres plugins. But they just show what is getting received from the call. With IE, i can also use this received data to interact with my site, really using this JSON and simulating my final project. Or am i wrong ?

Comment: I dont know what you are talking about , you can see the rest calls being made in the final project by pressing F12 in chrome and going to Network tab, there you can see all the REST endpoints , you can do similar things for firefox or IE . You can then go to source tab and put breakpoints in your code, change values in run-time and see the output in your application live.